# Reuse query in many object context

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I was working this weekend on parallelizing a section of code using Tasks to run all the queries I needed for a dashboard page.

What I have now is many copy/paste methods with almost exactly the same query and a different line at the very end of the method.

Is there a way to write a query against one object context then detach it and pass to a method?

I want to do something like this:

```
using(DbContext db = new DbContext)
{
   var query = db.cars.where(x => x.make == "Ford");

   int handleCounts = getDoorHandleCounts(query);
}

public int getDoorHandleCounts(type? query)
{
     using(DbContext db = new DbContext())
     {
          return query.where(x => x.partType == "DoorHandle").Count();
     }
 }
```

Any ideas?

Keep in mind all my count() methods are launched from a Task array so they'll be running in parallel. I need a new object context to run each count query on.

I've done some googling and thought about trying to use a pre-compiled query and call it from different object context's, but my real query is kind of complex with allot of if blocks to determine the where condition. Can you compile a query that isn't really simple?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't detach and attach a query from/to a context. However, you could reuse the first expression:

```
Expression<Func<Car,bool>> InitialSelection()
{
    return x => x.make == "Ford";
}

public int GetDoorHandleCounts()
{
    using(DbContext db = new DbContext())
    {
        return db.Cars()
               .Where(InitialSelection())
               .Where(x => x.partType == "DoorHandle").Count();
    }
}
```

And in your task:

```
int handleCounts = getDoorHandleCounts();
```

This only works if the initial query is "simple", i.e. does not contain joins and predicates on joined sets that you should repeat over and over in each `getX` method.

As an alternative, you could initialize a context and feed it to a method that returns a query:

```
public IQueryable<Car> GetInitialQuery(DbContext db)
{
    return db.Cars().Join(....)
           .Where(x => x.make == "Ford")
           .Where(....);
}

public int GetDoorHandleCounts()
{
    using(DbContext db = new DbContext())
    {
        return GetInitialQuery(db)
               .Where(x => x.partType == "DoorHandle").Count();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question, but wouldn't this do what you're looking for?

```
using(DbContext db = new DbContext)
{
   var carsResult = db.cars.where(x => x.make == "Ford");

   int handleCounts = getDoorHandleCounts(carsResult);
}

public int getDoorHandleCounts(IEnumerable<Car> result)
{
     return result.where(x => x.partType == "DoorHandle").Count();         
}
```

Edit: never mind, I only now saw your mention of the Task array.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
public int getDoorHandleCounts(type? query)
```

to

```
public int getDoorHandleCounts(IQueryable<cars> query)
```

And replace `cars` with the of objects the query will return.

**Edit**

I would just recommend passing value you're looking to filter on, like this:

```
{
   ...
   int handleCounts = getDoorHandleCounts("Ford");
}

public int getDoorHandleCounts(string Make)
{
     using(DbContext db = new DbContext())
     {
          return db.cars.where(x => x.make == Make && x.partType == "DoorHandle").Count();
     }
 }
```

Comment: Interesting, so if I pass my query as an IQueryable I can run it against a different object context then I created it with?

Comment: No, just realized that's what you were trying to do. Why can you pass the original filter and recreate the query every pass?

Comment: That sounds like what I'd like to do, do you have any references I can look over or examples maybe?

Comment: I was just saying to pass the string value of the filter, then create a new query. See my edit.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. 

That's similiar to what I'm doing now, but the where clause is kind of large and will be bad for maintenance/readability to have it split up across many different methods. I'd like to figure out a way to pass the base query if possible and just tack on one last where and a count call at the end.